# Change microphone voice with Python (in Windows)

Tags: python

I would like to replicate the [Clownfish](https://clownfish-translator.com/voicechanger/) app in Python.

I need to use Python to transmit an audio file to the microphone, on Windows, Linux, and Mac, such that if any service is listening to the microphone (for example, skype), it would catch that audio I'm transmitting.

Is there any way to transmit audio through the user's microphone?

There's [pyvoicechanger](https://github.com/capturePointer/pyvoicechanger) which works only for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).

Looks like you could use **wire** or **wire (callback)**.

```
PyAudio Example: Make a wire between input and output (i.e., record a
few samples and play them back immediately).
```

Another library you should take a look at is [python-sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.15/).

Comment: Thanks. Wiring seems to record the microphone, and transmit to the speakers. I would like to transmit audio to the microphone, such that an app listening to the microphone would pick up the transmission